# Конфликт имен при использования связки JavaScript и Angular 6

Tags: angular

Есть своя написанная js библиотека, добавил её в angular.json, она добавляться все хорошо.
Использую её в html файле:

```
<div class="video-cover" id="videoPlayer" data-title="{{title.name}} ({{title.year}})"></div>
```

Вот тут и начинаются проблемы, при компиляции **data-title** меняет свое название на **title** из-за конфликта имен. Соответственно JS перестает выполнять свой функционал...
Менял название **data-title** на **data-name** выводит ошибку при компиляции:

```
ERROR in : Can't bind to 'data-name' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

<div ... [ERROR ->]data-name="{{title.name}} ({{title.year}})"></div>
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: вы не полностью описали проблему, какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: если вы хотите засеттить атрибут - `attr.data-title="{{ title.name }} ({{ title.year }})"`

Comment: @overthesanity вы все правильно поняли спасибо!)

Comment: @overthesanity но теперь появилось новая проблема, JS не воспроизводит свой сценарий...

Comment: ставьте брейкпоинты, смотрите что именно не работает, возможно эксепшены какие-то, также установите опцию компилятора `"allowJs": true`, но имхо с JS'ом неудобно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите засеттить атрибут - то для этого используется модификатор `attr`.

У компилятора под капотом есть большая схема в виде `tagName^[constructor]|...attributes` (например `input^[HTMLElement]|accept,align,alt,autocapitalize,autocomplete......`), после парсинга шаблона линквощик прогоняет AST через эту схему и проверяет не используете ли вы неизвестные атрибуты. Поэтому при использовании известных атрибутов, типа `disabled`, вам не нужно писать `attr.disabled`, а `disabled="{{ expression }}"` вполне достаточно.

В вашем случае линковщик не понимает, что такое `data-title` - атрибут или входное свойство какой-то директивы, вам нужно явно указать модификатор `attr`:

```
attr.data-title="{{ title.name }} ({{ title.year }})"
```

Или:

```
[attr.data-title]="title.name + '(' + title.year + ')'"
```

Думаю второй вариант не очень удобен и не читабелен, поэтому первый вполне сгодится.